# Parsing 2D array into CSV file using OpenCSV

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am trying to write a 2D array into a CSV file using `OpenCSV` API. I have the following method:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/Users/Home/");
    String[][] d = new String[10][10];
    CSVWriter writer =
            new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(path.resolve("data.csv"),StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW));
    writer.writeNext(Arrays.asList(d));  // Does not work!
    writer.close();
```

In fact, `writer.writeNext(Arrays.asList(d))` does not work and I am getting stuck in this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs of CSVWriter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[])) `writeNext` expects a String array. You could iterate as follows

```
for (int i=0; i < d.length; i++) {
   writer.writeNext(d[i]);
}
```